# Create Element From Dynamic HTML String

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm working on a custom gutenberg block, and in the `save` method, I have dynamically changing HTML in the form of a string.

```js
element.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    contentString,
)
```

The above snippet just outputs the HTML as a string, converting all the symbols to HTML entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.)

How can I go about writing the actual HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslysetinnerhtml`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), a special HTML attribute in React:

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML`
>   in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky
>   because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a [cross-site
>   scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
>   attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type
>   out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key,
>   to remind yourself that it’s *dangerous*.

- ES5:

  ```js
  wp.element.createElement( 'div', {
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
          __html: '<b>HTML</b> here'
      }
  } );
  ```
- JSX+ESNext:

  ```js
  const createMarkup = ( html ) => { return { __html: html } };

  const my_element = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ createMarkup('<b>HTML</b> here') }></div>;
  ```

Or in Gutenberg, you can use [`wp.element.RawHTML()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/#RawHTML) which basically does the same thing as the snippets above.

- ES5:

  ```js
  wp.element.RawHTML( {
      children: '<b>HTML</b> here'
  } );
  ```
- JSX+ESNext:

  ```js
  import { RawHTML } from '@wordpress/element';

  const my_html = 'some dynamic <b>HTML</b> here!';

  const my_element = <RawHTML>{ my_html }</RawHTML>;
  ```

Comment: `const { RawHTML } = wp.element;`
`<RawHTML>{ content }</RawHTML>`

Comment: @madhushankarox, I don't know what your question is, but yes, you could also use the "const way" - `const { RawHTML } = wp.element`

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t tested it, but you might want to try:

```
element.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    {dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html: contentString}},
)
```

Comment: The `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is actually a HTML attribute and as such, it belongs in the *second* parameter which is a list of attributes for the element. Your code as it is now will throw an error.. :)

Comment: thanks for the correction. Always a bad idea to post untested code...