# How to add a link in a translation in gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I've created a block and in the sidebar I've some instructions with a link. But it gets escaped.
[image: The rendered escaped output]

The (relevant) code:

```js
    import {__, sprintf} from '@wordpress/i18n';

    const documentation_url = 'http://example.com';

    // the rest
    return (
        <InspectorControls key="settting">
            /* the rest */
            {sprintf(
                /* translators: url %s */
                __('The <a href="%s">documentation</a> is updated daily', 'mindd'),
                documentation_url
            )}
            /* the rest */
        </InspectorControls>
    );
```

I know I could transform/rearrange the sentence so it's all in an `<a>` but I want to know how to do this.

Comment: It gets escaped because that's the way it is - the `{ sprintf() }` returns a HTML string so React escaped it instead of parsing the HTML. However, if you must, you can use `wp.element.RawHTML()` as shown in my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344485/create-element-from-dynamic-html-string/344498#344498). But do take note of the warning there or [see an updated one here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: A potential simple workaround would be to split this into two items: `The documentation is updated daily.` and then a link with the text `View documentation`.

Comment: @SallyCJ that works, too bad to hear it's basicly a replacement for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but good to know

Comment: @Phil I know, I said so in the last sentence of the question. I want to know if there are other options.